# How to click controls in YouTube iframe behind smaller div positioned on top of it?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, z-index

I have an `iframe` containing either a YouTube or Vimeo video for which I want to make certain controls un-clickable (settings, full screen etc). This is because the user should only be able to play, pause and change the volume of the video. The application is intended for users with cognitive disabilities so we don't want them to navigate away from the page onto YouTube nor mess around with settings.

```css
iframe {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}

div-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: -15px;
  width: 865px;
  height: 570px;
  z-index: 1;
}

div-2 {
  position: absolute;
  right: -15px;
  bottom: -15px;
  width: 133px;
  height: 85px;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div style="position:relative; width:835px; padding-bottom:56%; margin:0 auto;">
  <div class="div-1"></div>
  <div class="div-2"></div>
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/786523922?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;transparent=0" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

The solution that was in place for the last few years suddenly stopped working about one month ago. That was adding two `div`s on top of the `iframe` that would cover the main area of the video and the bottom right containing some of the controls. See screenshots below:
[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

When you try to click on any of the parts of the `iframe` that are not covered, nothing happens. The invisible parts of the `div`s are covering the `iframe`. `pointer-events: none`; on the `div`s does not work. It's also not a z-index problem as I've tried removing z-index and let the stacking context to its job; same result. Here are the `CSS` properties of the elements:

This is only a problem in Chrome and has started occurring about a month ago. I have tried this in Firefox and Safari so I'm thinking an update changed some stacking context logic. Has anybody experienced this?

Comment: There are parameters you can add or remove from the Youtube embed code, which disables fullscreen, controls etc. Why not play around with those?

Comment: The problem with that is that you can only disable all the controls or none. You can't affect each one individually :)

Comment: What is the purpose of `div-1`? I would *expect* that to cover the video and make it unclickable.

Comment: @ralph.m yes exactly. But it's only covering the video itself, not the controls bar. That being said, even if I entirely remove div-1, div-2 would still make the whole iframe unclickable.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to wrap a div around the iframe instead and set it to position: relative. That's what I normally do with YouTube videos, as you can then set padding on the div that allows the video to be responsive. It might be more robust to place the covering divs within that context. I could do a little demo if you like.

Comment: There is a div with position relative around the iframe and the two other divs already :) I will update the post with the html structure. Sorry about that :)

Comment: _"pointer-events: none; on the divs does not work"_ - you _want_ those div elements to "catch" the clicks, so to tell them to _ignore_ all pointer events, would make absolutely no sense whatsoever here.

Comment: I want the area where the divs are to stop all click events. To my knowledge, that's what "pointer-events: none" does. Then the rest of the space where there are no divs should be clickable e.g. play button and volume